# Displaying XSLT Variable in <xsl:message> not working

Tags: variables, xslt

When trying to display the value of a variable with `<xsl:message select="$Direct">` we can't see the value.

```
<xsl:variable name="Direct">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring(//E2EDK02[E2EDK02_QUALF='001'][1]/E2EDK02_BELNR, 1, 4)='4500'">
            <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                 </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring(//E2EDK02[E2EDK02_QUALF='001'][1]/E2EDK02_BELNR, 1, 2)='80'">
                 <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

This next statement gives us no value:

```
<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$Direct)"/></xsl:message>
```

Adding this concat made it work but why?

```
<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="concat('Direct Flag: ', $Direct)"/></xsl:message>
```

Comment: Post minimal but complete code samples to allow others to reproduce the problem; also state exactly which version of which XSLT processor you use.

Comment: We are using Saxon 8.9.  That was the complete code but I see the message statements weren't captured in the code window, I assume because of my questions?

Comment: <xsl:variable name="Direct">
      <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="E2EDK02_BELNR, 1, 4)='4500'">
                 <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="E2EDK02_BELNR, 1, 2)='80'">
                  <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                   <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
             </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

 

            <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="concat('Direct Flag: ', $Direct)"/></xsl:message>

Comment: We use Saxon 8.9.  All the code wasn't captured in the code window I assume because of my questions in there.  I don't know how to correct that and tried to paste the code again   but it is just a comment now.   That is the complete code where we define and try to display the variable.  Until I added the concat to the message select we saw no output.

Comment: I edited the question to include the required Markdown codes.

Comment: Please when asked edit your question not add comments to it (which may not be read)

Answer (score 2):

The code as you showed it says `select="$Direct)"` which is an invalid XPath expression. I would expect that to be reported as an error, but Saxon 8.9 is an incredibly old release -- you really shouldn't be using something so ancient.

I strongly suspect that you made some typo and this wasn't your actual code, but if that's the case, then it's very hard to help you.

The current specification says:

> Any dynamic error that occurs while evaluating the select expression
> [of xsl:message]
> or the contained sequence constructor, and any serialization error
> that occurs while processing the result, does not cause the
> transformation to fail; at worst, it means that no message is output,
> or that the only message that is output is one that relates to the
> error that occurred.

But I suspect that was written long after Saxon 8.9 was released.